# how to prove the commutativity of union and pullback without element?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, category-theory, homological-algebra

Suppose F -> E and {U(i) -> E :a monomrphism} ,
how to prove the fibre product of F and the union of {U(i)} is the union of {the fibre products of F and U(i)} ?

I think the union of {U(i) -> E} can be defined as the limit of {subobject U of E such that U(i,j) -> U(i) -> U =  U(i,j)-> U(j) -> U, where U(i,j) is the fibre product of U(i) and U(j)}.

If, in general, we can't prove this, how to define "the union" without elements suitably to make the statement true?

Comment: Are you working in a specific category ?

Comment: with limits and colimits

Comment: There is no reasonable definition that will always make this true.

Comment: what kind of natural conditions without elements can make this true?

Comment: The most natural condition is simply to ask for this condition directly – see e.g. the definition of coherent/geometric categories.

Answer (score 2):

An object $U$ together with a monomorphism $U\to E$ is often called a *subobject* of $E$.  If $f:U\to E$ and $g:V\to E$ are subobjects, we say $U$ is *contained* in $V$ (and write $U\leq V$) if $f$ factors through $g$: that is, there is a map $h:U\to V$ such that $gh=f$.  Note that since $g$ is monic, such an $h$ is unique if it exists.

The usual definition of a union (or "join") of subobjects $U(i)\to E$ is the smallest subobject $U\to E$ which contains every $U(i)$, if such a subobject exists.  That is, $U$ is a subobject of $E$ such that $U(i)\leq U$ for all $U$ and if $V$ is a subobject of $E$ such that $U(i)\leq E$ for all $i$, then $U\leq V$.  This need not coincide with your definition of the union as a colimit, essentially because there is no reason in general that the map from the colimit to $E$ should be monic.

In any case, for either definition, the following is a counterexample to your question.  Consider the poset $\{E,U(1),U(2),F,0\}$ considered as a category, where $0$ is the least element, $E$ is the greatest element, and $U(1)$, $U(2)$, and $F$ are pairwise incomparable (as in [this picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/M_3_mit_Beschriftung.svg)).  This is a complete lattice, so it has all limits and colimits.  The union of $U(1)$ and $U(2)$ as subobjects of $E$ is $E$, and the pullback of this union with $F$ is $F$.  But the pullback of each $U(i)$ with $F$ is $0$, and so the union of these pullbacks is $0$, not $F$.

Comment: ok, actually, I'm working in the category of topological spaces, and I want to define a "cover" by catigorical properties without using elements, how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "cover"?  (That is, how would you define it set-theoretically?)

Comment: at least it has above property. here, "cover" I mean  an open cover.

Comment: I don't think there's a particularly nice way to define open subsets of a topological space categorically.  The typical approach to this kind of thing is to make the notion of a "cover" an additional piece of _structure_ on your category, rather than something you can define intrinsically from just its categorical structure.  You then assume things like the stability under pullback that you're asking for as an _axiom_ of this additional structure. (See, for instance, the definition of a [Grothendieck topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_topology).)

Comment: There isn't a _nice_ way but it can be done. And once you know what opens are you can define open covers to be jointly epimorphic collections of open embeddings. But the fact that they are preserved by pullback doesn't come for free...